# How to perform the task in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

As its a quite well-know fact that the processor heavy work needs to be on the Non-UI thread, lets consider it as the Background thread. Now in my case I'm parsing data from feed and then inserting those parsed data into the DataBase. I want to handle this 'Data Parsing' on my **Background thread**, keeping the `UI` thread **Responsive** to user interactions. Now my idea is to start this parsing as soon as the app launches.

**I have absolutely no idea about how to handle threads in IOS.**

Please someone help me.

Comment: `I have absolutely no idea about how to handle threads in IOS.` ... Read books !

Answer (score 2):

Rohan, If you're expecting to download data from a server, insert the data into the local database on your device and order is important, then I suggest you research into asynchronous request such as using **ASIHttpRequest** or **AFNetworking** libraries.

This is better than using Multi-threaded programming.

I'm no guru but from my own experience, I have found that multi-threaded programming is more for doing calculations in the background and not downloading data in the background. Asynchronous request is more for downloading data in the background.

Have to use the right tool for the right job.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you searched a bit more you would have found something... This one is for free:

```
// Declare the queue
         dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
         dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                        ^{
                          // My background job
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                           ^{
                                              // Update the UI
                                           }
                                           );
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way is to use this NSObject's method:

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg;
```

That should invoke a method that will run in background, parsing the data.
When you have finished you may need to notify the main thread.So you can execute a completion handler in the main thread:

```
NSBlockOperation* completionHandler=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^
{
    // Use the parsed data
}];
NSOperationQueue* queue=[NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[queue addOperation: completionHandler];
```

**PS**: This should be used in the background method once it has finished parsing the data.**I assumed that you need to update something that may create a race condition with the main thread**.